# My ListView is hiding behind my parent layout when visibility is set to View.GONE

Tags: android, xml, listview

I am trying to set my list view when I click on image, it should be hidden or shown but the problem is that when I inflate my list view in my activity, it is hiding behind and not taking complete space. When I perform on click event it opens behind the parent layout.
[SNAPSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEyhP.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.bitblue.dextronewproject.Avtivity.ReportActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/main_linear_layout">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Fees History"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/studentlogin" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Receipt"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Date"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/r_tablelayoutRAD"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </TableLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5.5"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drop_down_round_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_2"
        android:id="@+id/lisstview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

    </ListView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Unpaid"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="monospace" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/studentlogin" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/un_paid_list_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </ListView>








</LinearLayout>





</RelativeLayout>
```

Your effort is appreciable.Thanks in andvance

Comment: where is the screenshot?

Comment: which listview are you talking about here? There are two.

Comment: there is link and for both the listview

Comment: Add `android:layout_below="@+id/ll_2"` to listview

Comment: the parent layout is overlaping my listview

Answer (score 0):

Your parent layouts are not matching. You have used layout_below in LinearlLayout where the parent is not RelativeLayout. Check the hierarchy of the layouts in your layout.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.bitblue.dextronewproject.Avtivity.ReportActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Fees History"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/studentlogin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:id="@+id/view1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
        android:id="@+id/ll1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Receipt"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Date"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/r_tablelayoutRAD"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </TableLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/drop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5.5"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_drop_down_round_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll_2"
        android:id="@+id/lisstview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Unpaid"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lisstview"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:id="@+id/ll3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="Type"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"
            android:text="Amount"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:typeface="monospace" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/studentlogin"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll3"
        android:id="@+id/view3"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/un_paid_list_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ll3"/>
```

Comment: what is the diffrence

Comment: in layout_below attribute, you've used @id/ll_2 instead of @+id/ll_2. @id is used for ids which are there in the android system while @+id is used for id of views defined by the programmer

Comment: still it is hiding behing parent layout

Comment: Hope this helps. Please accept the answer if it solves your issue